# Solar Charge circuit verification

Tags: battery-charging, solar-cell

I am designing the solar charge controller which will charge [12v battery](https://file.talaweb.com/u1015446/home/V%C3%A2n/b%C3%ACnh%20%E1%BA%AFc%20quy%20CHLORIDE.jpg) and will also protect it from over charge and dischage and will also control load. I searched a lot of articles on google and found out this [article](http://www.instructables.com/id/ARDUINO-SOLAR-CHARGE-CONTROLLER-Version-20/?ALLSTEPS) which uses a transistors and mosfet and an arduino. But instead of transistors and mosfet, can we  use optocoupler [PC817](http://www.sharp-world.com/products/device/lineup/data/pdf/datasheet/pc817xnnsz_e.pdf) for this purpose. I have made a following schematic and want to know what will be its drawbacks. Will this work properly in order to charge a battery.

[image]

**Circuit Explanation:**

Three PVT connectors are there for Solar panel, battery and load connections. Voltage divider circuit are used to monitor the voltage of solar panel and battery. So using `analogRead(A1)` we can read the battery voltage. If its low, then we can turn on the IO Pin6 which will connect the solar panel to battery so battery will start charging. If the battery is fully charged, then we can turn off the IO pin6 which will stop further charging of battery. In this case, we will turn on the IO pin7 to connect the load to battery and then load will start working.

Will this circuit work properly.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not good idea.
Optocouplers are not intended to drive power. Maximum rating of PC817 of forward current is 50mA. You cannot exceed that. In reality, you should be well below that. If you want islotion, just use power mosfets and drive them by optocouplers.